# Assigning values to arrays from a text file?

Tags: java

I'm using numbers from a text file, I'm also using variable val2 as an array of numbers. I'm trying to assign variable val3 as values to assign to the array variable val2, but I keep getting the default 0 value. How do I fix it?

[This is the contents of the text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wHasvgQ9Xc0W-CSFLnq8Fx851tNHygs7)

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    java.io.File myfile;

    String mypath;
    mypath = "/Users/hayleysegan/Downloads";
    myfile = new java.io.File(mypath + "/studynotes.txt");
    Scanner arraytext = new Scanner(myfile);
    int val1,val2,val3;
    val1 = arraytext.nextInt();
    val2 = arraytext.nextInt();
    val3 = arraytext.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Money Value");
    int[]a = new int[11];
      while(val1 != -1){

        if(val1 == 1){
            a[val2] = a[val2]+val3;
        }else if (val1 == 2){
            a[val2] = a[val2]-val3;
            }
        val1 = arraytext.nextInt();
        val2 = arraytext.nextInt();
        val3 = arraytext.nextInt();

        System.out.println(val1 + "\t"+a[val2]);
        }

        }



        }
```

My output:

Money Value
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: Please edit your question to include the content of your "studynotes.txt" file.

Comment: please add your inputs

Comment: What does your input, `studynotes.txt` look like? Can I see your input please?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the text file.

Comment: @Tony Don't add the content as a screenshot, it makes it difficult to copy the content.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I added a link to the text file

Comment: @Tony Don't add the content as a link either, the link might get deleted and then it cannot be checked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you run the `System.out.println()` statement after you already have read the next values with the three `nextInt()` calls. This means that the following access to `a[val2]` will point to the next array element and not the one you have changed in the current loop iteration.

You need to output your line before you read the next line, so `a[val2]` will still be the same array element you have just changed.